# Скрипт в Google Spreadsheets. Как отследить событие изменения в ячейке?

Tags: javascript, события, google-spreadsheet, google-apps-script

Всем добрый день. Составляем файлик, где будем вести семейный бюджет. Столкнулся со следующей задачей. Есть "направление" и "категория продуктов". В одном направлении собраны определенные категории продуктов. Также есть форма ввода (типа опроса), что бы мы могли забивать транзакции через мобильники. Так вот, нужно чтобы скрипт анализировал категорию продуктов и автоматом проставлял направление. Допустим категория "метро", автоматом проставляется в соседнем столбце направление "транспорт". Я написал пример скрипта, который читает содержимое текущей ячейки и проставляет результаты в первой. Вопрос в том, как это все повесить на событие ввода (нажал enter - скрипт отработал)

```
function myFunction() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
//  var first = Browser.inputBox("First value");
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue() == "пиво"){
    sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(SpreadsheetApp.getActiveRange().getValue());}
//  sheet.getRange("A1").setValue("First value:");
//  sheet.getRange("B1").setValue(first);
//  var next = Browser.inputBox("Next value"); 
//  sheet.getRange("A2").setValue("Next value:");
//  sheet.getRange("B2").setValue(next);
//  var result = sheet.getRange("B1").getValue() + sheet.getRange("B2").getValue();
//  sheet.getRange("A3").setValue("Result:");
//  sheet.getRange("B3").setValue(result);
//  Browser.msgBox("Summ is: " + result);
  ss.addMenu("Test", [{name: "Test", functionName: "myFunction"}]);
}
```

Comment: В данном случае возможно использовать готовое бесплатное решение [bkper.com](http://bkper.com) Приложение имеет ряд преимуществ и несколько вариантов интеграции с Диском Google (загрузка сканов с Диска, импорт значений в Таблицу через дополнения)

Answer (score 7):

Вероятно, использовать триггер [onEdit(event)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guide_events#Simple):

> **onEdit(event)**
>
> The onEdit function runs automatically when any cell of the spreadsheet is edited. A very simple use case for onEdit is to record the last modified time in a comment on the cell that was edited. The argument e that is passed in to the function contains a single property, source , which is the spreadsheet that is being edited.
>
> ```
> function onEdit(event)
> {
>   var ss = event.source.getActiveSheet();
>   var r = event.source.getActiveRange();
>   r.setComment("Last modified: " + (new Date()));
> }
> ```

Answer (score 4):

Все очень просто, используйте функцию onEdit(event) которая реагирует только на изменение данных в таблице.
Пример готового решения который при изменение любой строки вносит данные в столбец номер 8, номера строки та которая была изменена Вами

```
function onEdit(event) {


  var sheet = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var sheetName = event.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() // Получаем имя листа который активен 
  var actRng = event.source.getActiveRange();
  var index = actRng.getRowIndex();


  if (index > 1 && sheetName == "Менеджер") {
  Logger.log(event.source.parameters);
  //var user = Session.getEffectiveUser().getEmail();
  var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  Logger.log(index);
  sheet.getRange(index, 8).setValue(user);
}
```

Исходя из Вашей задачи Вам осталось только переписать условие iF.